# How can I show only some Badges in the Badges list?

Tags: feature-request, badges, lists

In the Badges page, you can see all the Badges, with a check next to the ones you have. You can also select how to sort the Badges, which ones to filter out.
  Now, **can I somehow sort the list by times awarded, or for example show only bronze unawares badges?**

Comment: What's the problem with this question?

Comment: Given the nature of the question this sounds more like [support] ("how can I do this?") than [feature-request] ("please let me do this"). Given you've tagged it as a feature request though, probably people are voting based on whether they think the feature is worthwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and given that the list of badges is very small, this feature is a lot of effort for very little gain. If you really want to sort/filter the badge data I suggest you copy it into a spreadsheet, or use [the data api](https://data.stackexchange.com/).